# /_rels/.rels: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the error seen in the title when I attempt to unzip a .xlsx file. I have write permissions in my manifest. It unzips the first file fine [Content_Types].xml but cannot unzip the others.

Here's my unzip code....

```
public void unzip(String filepath, String filename) throws IOException {
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath + filename);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

try {
    ZipEntry ze;
    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;

        String filename_temp = ze.getName();
        if (ze.isDirectory()) {
            File fmd = new File(filepath + filename_temp);
            fmd.mkdirs();
        } else {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filepath + filename_temp);
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                fout.write(bytes);
                baos.reset();
            }

            fout.close();
        }
    }
} finally {
    zis.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an android app developer. But I encountered this same problem in Golang. The problem is not with the file, its with the folder. You have to set create permission for the folder _rels. In my case I was extracting a .docx file and I only needed the data file which was "word/document.xml" so I set permission for folder "word" and extracted that folder alone. If you too are looking for the data file of .xlsx then it is "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml". In your case you have to give permission for both "xl" and "worksheets".
Hoping this will help.

NB: My android knowledge is very limited, but I think you have to write permission for accessing an external file or folder on the source code itself, not on manifest file.